# Evaluating an integral of a very large function multiplied by a very small function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Within a numerical simulation I'm trying to evaluate the function

$$y = \exp(-at) \int_0^t \exp(at') P(t') \, dt'$$

where $a$ is a very large constant and $P(t')$ is an imported dataset that cannot easily be described analytically or known in advance.

I encounter the problem that $\exp(at)$ is far too large a number for the software to handle (floating point error) and $\exp(-at)$ is far too small a number for the software to handle (zero value).

Is there a way I can reformulate the integral so that I am not calculating very large/small numbers?

Thanks in advance.

ps. This is my first post on a maths forum for getting on for 15 years so apologies if it is a dumb or poorly-posed question.

Comment: misread question.

Comment: By the substitution $ u = t - t'$, you can easily check that

$$ y = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-au} P(t - u) \, du. $$

I guess this form is better suited for numerical computation.

Comment: Thanks @SangchulLee. That's clever. I like it but unfortunately I cannot manipulate $P(t)$ in that way as it is not an analytical function, just an imported data set.

Comment: In what form does $P(t)$ come? As a set of equally-spaced samples $\{t_n, P_n\}$? If so, you can use the convolution theorem to evaluate this whole thing using fast Fourier transforms.

Comment: @JohnBarber Thanks for the suggestion. I was considering something like this but it wouldn't be my preferred method as the integral needs evaluating every time step (current 1800, but potentially far more as the model is enhanced) and at a large number of spatial points (currently 40000, but, again, potentially far more as the model is enhanced). That's a hell of a lot of FFTs! The approximation approach described in the answer below lends itself much better to my present requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite the integral to be

$$ \int_0^t e^{-a(t-t')}P(t') dt'$$

Then you should see that the integrand is dominated by the region where $t-t'\approx 0$.  Therefore, you write

$$ \int_0^t e^{a(t'-t)}[P(t) + P'(t)(t'-t)+...]$$
The zeroth order term is then 
$$ P(t)\int_0^te^{a(t'-t)} = P(t)\left(\frac{1-e^{-at}}{a}\right)\approx \frac{P(t)}{a}$$
You can find higher order terms using repeated integration by parts, but each term will be surpressed by another power of $a$ so if it is indeed extremely large, you won't need many more.  Quantities like $P'(t)$ can be evaluated by any number of numerical differentiation schemes if you cannot treat them analytically.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot!